# Element Tree: How to parse subElements of child nodes

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I have an XML tree, which I'd like to parse using Elementtree. My XML looks something like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<GetOrdersResponse xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
<Ack>Success</Ack>
<Version>857</Version>
<Build>E857_INTL_APIXO_16643800_R1</Build>
<PaginationResult>
    <TotalNumberOfPages>1</TotalNumberOfPages>
    <TotalNumberOfEntries>2</TotalNumberOfEntries>
</PaginationResult>
<HasMoreOrders>false</HasMoreOrders>
<OrderArray>
    <Order>
        <OrderID>221362908003-1324471823012</OrderID>
        <CheckoutStatus>
            <eBayPaymentStatus>NoPaymentFailure</eBayPaymentStatus>
            <LastModifiedTime>2014-02-03T12:08:51.000Z</LastModifiedTime>
            <PaymentMethod>PaisaPayEscrow</PaymentMethod>
            <Status>Complete</Status>
            <IntegratedMerchantCreditCardEnabled>false</IntegratedMerchantCreditCardEnabled>
        </CheckoutStatus>
    </Order>
    <Order> ...
    </Order>
    <Order> ...
    </Order>
</OrderArray>
</GetOrdersResponse>
```

I want to parse the 6th child of the XML () I am able to get the value of subelements by index. E.g if I want OrderID of first order, i can use `root[5][0][0].text`. But, I would like to get the values of subElements by name. I tried the following code, but it does not print anything:

```
tree = ET.parse('response.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
for child in root:
    try:
        for ids in child.find('Order').find('OrderID'):
            print ids.text
    except:
        continue
```

Could someone please help me on his. Thanks

Comment: Remove the `try-except-continue` and post the traceback that you will  get.

Comment: @NigelTufnel : Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 7, in <module>
    for ids in child.find('Order').find('OrderID'):
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the XML document has a namespace declaration (`xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents"`), you have to use *universal names* when referring to elements in the document. For example, you need `{urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents}OrderID` instead of just `OrderID`.

This snippet prints all OrderIDs in the document:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

NS = "urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents"

tree = ET.parse('response.xml')

for elem in tree.iter("*"):    # Use tree.getiterator("*") in Python 2.5 and 2.6
    if elem.tag == '{%s}OrderID' % NS:
        print elem.text
```

See http://effbot.org/zone/element-namespaces.htm for details about ElementTree and namespaces.

Answer (score 1):

Try to avoid chaining your finds. If your first `find` does not find anything, it will return `None`.

```
for child in root:
    order = child.find('Order')
    if order is not None:
        ids = order.find('OrderID')
        print ids.text
```

Comment: Same thing again. Doesn't print anything

Comment: Are you sure? I just tested with your input and it prints the OrderID text.

Comment: Yes. Though your code is correct. I was not able to print anything because my root tag was `<GetOrdersResponse xmlns="urn:eBLBaseComponents">`. On removing the xmlns, i was able to print the ids

Answer (score 1):

You can find an `OrderArray` first and then just iterate its children by name:

```
tree = ET.parse('response.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
order_array = root.find("OrderArray")
for order in order_array.findall('Order'):
    order_id_element = order.find('OrderID')
    if order_id_element is not None:
        print order_id_element.text
```

A side note. Never ever use `except: continue`. It hides any exception you get and makes debugging really hard.

Comment: Nigel, I'm getting this error: `for order in order_array.findall('Order'):
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'findall'`

Comment: Nigel's answer works for me with the given input. Does your input match what you display in your question? A little better than mine since it restricts to "OrderArray" children.

Comment: Figured out that its not working due to the xmlns. Figuring out how I can ignore the xmlns programatically.