# Python ElementTree unable to parse xml file correctly

Tags: python

I am trying to Parse an XML file using elemenTree of Python.
The xml file is like below:

```
<App xmlns="test attribute">
    <name>sagar</name>
</App>
```

Parser Code:

```
from xml.etree.ElementTree import ElementTree
from xml.etree.ElementTree import Element
import xml.etree.ElementTree as etree
def parser():
    eleTree = etree.parse('app.xml')
    eleRoot = eleTree.getroot()
    print("Tag:"+str(eleRoot.tag)+"\nAttrib:"+str(eleRoot.attrib))
if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser()
```

Output:

```
[sagar@linux Parser]$ python test.py
Tag:{test attribute}App  <------------- It should print only "App"
Attrib:{}
```

When I remove "xmlns" attribute or rename "xmlns" attribute to something else the eleRoot.tag is printing correct value.
Why can't element tree unable to parse the tags properly when I have "xmlns" attribute in the tag. Am I missing some pre-requisite to parse an XML of this format using element tree?

Comment: I'd guess that `xmlns` attribute gets special handling, since it defines the namespace the tag comes from.

Comment: @Blckknght what is the special handling i need to do to make my code work.

Comment: The trouble isn't your code, but the xml. A small gotcha, that I just found [here](http://effbot.org/zone/element-namespaces.htm#element-tree-representation) is that when an element has an xml namespace defined it's qualified name is "{namespace_url}Tag". Thus in your example you have defined the default namespace of "test attribute" which means that the fully qualified name of your `App` element is in fact "{test attribute}App", which is what you get out. I'll be modifying my answer below to accommodate this information.

Comment: I found one solution to parse the subtags:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21531111/element-tree-how-to-parse-subelements-of-child-nodes

Answer (score 2):

Your xml uses the attribute `xmlns`, which is trying to define a default xml namespace. Xml namespaces are used to solve naming conflicts, and require a valid URI for their value, as such the value of `"test attribute"` is invalid, which appears to be troubling the parsing of your xml by `etree`.

For more information on xml namespaces see [XML Namespaces](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_namespaces.asp) at W3 Schools.

---

Edit:

After looking into the issue further it appears that the fully qualified name of an element when using a python's `ElementTree` has the form `{namespace_url}tag_name`. This means that, as you defined the default namespace of "test attribute", the fully qualified name of your "App" tag is infact `{test attribute}App`, which is what you're getting out of your program.

[Source](http://effbot.org/zone/element-namespaces.htm#element-tree-representation)